# How to run elasticsearch as a service on CentOS 5

Tags: linux, elasticsearch, centos5

I found only this [official guide](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.3/setup-service.html) to install Elasticsearch 2.0 as a service but there is no mention of CENTOS5.
What are the steps to install ES as a service on CentOS5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CentOS is based on RedHat and should use the RPM distribution, start it as follows:

```
sudo /sbin/chkconfig --add elasticsearch
sudo service elasticsearch start
```

Comment: I installed ES in the home of a user because I have no access to the Yum repo. Is this also work? (don't want to break something)

Comment: Does the file `/etc/init.d/elasticsearch` exist? if not, I recommend you download the rpm from the Elastic website and install that.